# Merging sheets (2) from multiple excel workbooks in one while using information from sheet (1)

Tags: r, excel, merge, repeat

I have 200 workbooks (1 per subject) with two sheets each. I was able to merge all sheets 1 and all sheets 2 in two separate data frames using the following script:

```
#create a list with the data from all the subjects (the folder needs to contain all your data)
my_files <- list.files(pattern="*.lsx")
my_files

#combine the second sheets in one dataset
students_data = lapply(my_files, function(i){
  x = read_excel(i, sheet=2)
  x
})
students_data[[1]]
students_data = do.call("rbind.data.frame", students_data)
```

However, when merging the second sheet from every workbook I would also like to keep the subjID variable which is only listed in the first sheet.
So, my original dataset is like this:
[Sheet 1 of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8M2L.png)
[Sheet 2 of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3KOF.png)
What I would like to have is all sheets 2 combined (and I did this with the above code) but with the id of the subject repeated for every 3 rows:
[Final desired dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et398.png)

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the student ids in Sheet 1 while reading the data from Sheet 2, as follows, this assumes there's a single id for each file.

```r
students_data = lapply(my_files, function(i){
  x = read_excel(i, sheet=2)
  
  # Get sheet 1 for each file
  student_ids = read_excel(2, sheet=1)
  # Get the id 
  SubjID = unique(student_ids["participant_num"])
  # Create a df with the id in a single column, with the same rows
  # as the data frame from sheet 2
  SubjID_df = data.frame("SubjID" = rep(SubjID, nrow(x)))
  
  # Bind the data frame with ids and with the data in
  # sheet 2
  std_data = cbind.data.frame(SubjID_df, x)
  
  std_data
})
```

Then you can proceed as usual, binding all resulting data frames.

Comment: If I try your script I receive: Error: `path` must be a string